# inconsistent indentation while using sass

Tags: sass

I am using scss format for sass (I am using brackets).  When I use the watch command (sass --watch "folder where I have all my sass files"), I am getting the following error message:

```
error sass (Line 37: Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 8 spaces.)
```

Does the line number correspond to the line number in the resulting css file, the scss file or something else (I am including partials into my base.scss file).

Line 37 in my base.scss file is indented in the same fashion as other lines.

```
   font-family: Arial;
```

Comment: update: I was watching the wrong folder.  I do not have any issues with the scss file now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pilot error:  I was using the watch command on the wrong folder.  After I switched over to the correct folder, I was able to compile the sass files.

Comment: I had the same with sass 4.0 - I called it in project/css/ folder and was getting those strange indentation errors that didn't make any sense. Calling `sass --watch css:css` in project/ made it work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using your new codes from an existing file, you need to make sure that your text editor is selected to 'Tab Size' (in Brackets IO you can find it at the bottom - right of the text editor). I changed to 'Tab Size' from 'Spaces' in my text editor and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says

```
Line 37: 2 spaces were used, but the rest uses 8 spaces.
```

So if you're writing:

`p
  color: black`

you'll see there is **2 spaces before** "color: black"
but your **other codes has 8 spaces**:

`a
        color: black`
Make sure that every one of them has the same size of spaces.

You can simply use [enter] key once after you write the selector ("p" or "a" etc.)